# How to delete a specific row in Material UI DataGrid (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, material-ui

I'm starting this project in react & currently it's going well.
However, I'm having an issue.

My desired functionality is this: I desire to delete every row that you see where the checkbox for that row is clicked. For example, if I click the checkbox in rows 1 & 3, I want rows 1 & 3 to be deleted. I also want to keep track of the rows that I decide to delete.

The issue is that I have no idea how to do that, and even after doing research I still feel stuck on how to approach this problem.

Currently I'm populating this table with some sample JSON data I found online, so don't mind the weird data that's present. Also, if anybody has recommendations for an easier or cleaner way to achieve this, then feel free to let me know about it in the comments.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerName: 'Age',
      type: 'number',
      width: 90,
    },
    {
      field: 'fullName',
      headerName: 'Full name',
      description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
      sortable: false,
      width: 160,
      valueGetter: (params) =>
        `${params.getValue('firstName') || ''} ${params.getValue('lastName') || ''}`,
    },
    { field: 'city', headerName: 'City', width: 100 },
    { field: 'state', headerName: 'State', width: 100 },
  ];
  
  const rows = [
    { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35, city: 'Milwaukee', state: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42, city: 'Dubuque', state: 'Iowa' },
    { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45, city: 'Appleton', state: 'Wisconsin'},
    { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16, city: 'Madison', state: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryenmnsdlfbsjbgjksbgksbfksfgbk', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null, city: 'Green Bay', state: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150, city: 'San Antonio', state: 'Texas' }, 
    { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44, city: 'Dallas', state: 'Texas' },
    { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36, city: 'Brooklyn', state: 'New York' },
    { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65, city: 'Toledo', state: 'Ohio' },
    { id: 10, lastName: 'Larry', firstName: 'King', age: 105, city: 'Chicago', state: 'Illiniois' },
    { id: 11, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35, city: 'Milwaukee', state: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 12, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42, city: 'Dubuque', state: 'Iowa' },
    { id: 13, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45, city: 'Appleton', state: 'Wisconsin'},
    { id: 14, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16, city: 'Madison', state: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 15, lastName: 'Targaryenmnsdlfbsjbgjksbgksbfksfgbk', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null, city: 'Green Bay', state: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 16, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150, city: 'San Antonio', state: 'Texas' }, 
    { id: 17, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44, city: 'Dallas', state: 'Texas' },
    { id: 18, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36, city: 'Brooklyn', state: 'New York' },
    { id: 19, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65, city: 'Toledo', state: 'Ohio' },
    { id: 20, lastName: 'Larry', firstName: 'King', age: 105, city: 'Chicago', state: 'Illiniois' },
  ];

class ElgibleContracts extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <h1 style={{fontFamily: "Stone"}}>Elgible Contracts</h1>
                <span className="horizontal-line" />
                <div className="centerDiv" style={{ height: 380, width: 950}}>
                    <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={10} checkboxSelection />
                </div>
                <br />
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.getInfo} >Purge</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ElgibleContracts;
```

[image: The Screen that's displayed]

Answer (score 3):

I created a sandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-davinci-n3vrz?file=/src/App.js

I used functional components and hooks since this is best practice nowadays.

```
   const [rows, setRows] = useState(data);
   const [deletedRows, setDeletedRows] = useState([]);

   const handleRowSelection = (e) => {
    setDeletedRows([...deletedRows, ...rows.filter((r) => r.id === e.data.id)]);
  };

  const handlePurge = () => {
    setRows(
      rows.filter((r) => deletedRows.filter((sr) => sr.id === r.id).length < 1)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1 style={{ fontFamily: "Stone" }}>Elgible Contracts</h1>
      <span className="horizontal-line" />
      <div className="centerDiv" style={{ height: 380, width: 950 }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={10}
          checkboxSelection
          onRowSelected={handleRowSelection}
        />
      </div>
      <br />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handlePurge}>
        Purge
      </Button>
```

Comment: This just deletes it on checkbox click, but I wanted to delete the rows ONLY when I click the purge button. Any ideas for that? Thanks for the help so far, as well!

Comment: I've updated my answer and the sandbox for this! Check it out!

Comment: Thank you!!! Quick question, in future I have a history page that will show the user a history of what they deleted. My question is this - to access the deleteditems array in this component in my history component, do I just import this component & call deleteditems to get the deleted items? Thank you!

Comment: That would not work. If you need to use the deletedItems between different components. You have two options, either lift up the state (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or use a state manager like Redux (https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) or Mobx. If you need a demonstration of this, I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: I'd genuinely appreciate that. The idea is that after deleting rows from this page, they'll go to a page called history which will have the same tabular view & it'll show: total number of contracts, the number of contracts that were purged & the number of contracts that weren't purged. Next to the number of purged records will be a button that will show what records were purged. I know how to do that from a logic perpsective, but idk how to access the deleted rows & the whole dataset from this component

Comment: Hey @coder_coder123. I updated the sandbox to show more or less how it should be. I took the first approach, lifting up the state.

Comment: ok and LAST question before I stop bothering you: if I want to change it so that I delete EVERY record except ones that I clicked the checkboxes for, would I just replace the "===" with "!=="? I want to delete every record except for ones who have a checked checkbox near their id

Comment: No, wait. That's not enough. I can update the sandbox to work that way.

Comment: I was just gonna say that that isn't working, but okay. Just let me know once it's updated. Thank you!!!

Comment: I sent you a chat - let me know once you've received it. Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with this code: Select 3 rows, then unselect one of them and hit the "Purge" button... Instead of 2 rows all 3 rows will be deleted because once a row is selected, it ends up in `deletedRows` without getting removed from there when deselecting it.

Comment: Tried following along with this Sandbox a couple of days ago and it was working fine. I bookmarked it and came back to it today and was greeted with the following error. `×
ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'events/events.js' relative to '/node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid/dist/index-esm.js'`

Answer (score 1):

```
const ElgibleContracts = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(rows)
  const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState([]);
  const [deleted, setDeleted] = React.useState([])
  const handlePurge = () => {
    setDeleted([...deleted, ...selection])
    setItems(items.filter(i=> !selection.some(s=> s.id === i.id)))
    setSelection([])
  }
  console.log("Here are deleted items",deleted)
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <h1 style={{fontFamily: "Stone"}}>Elgible Contracts</h1>
                <span className="horizontal-line" />
                <div className="centerDiv" style={{ height: 380, width: 950}}>
                    <DataGrid  onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
          setSelection(newSelection.rows);
        }} rows={items} columns={columns} pageSize={10} checkboxSelection />
                </div>
                <br />
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handlePurge} >Purge</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: That won't even run for me. Idk if it's a syntax thing or logic thing

Comment: Nevermind, I made a stupid mistake. It works fine - thank you! lol

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `onRowSelected` can end up in errors quickly because you have to reset the `deletedRows` when unselecting items in the `DataGrid`. That's why I suggest to make use of `onSelectionModelChange`:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState(data);
const [deletedRows, setDeletedRows] = useState([]);

<DataGrid
  checkboxSelection
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={5}
  onSelectionModelChange={({selectionModel}) => {
    const rowIds = selectionModel.map(rowId => parseInt(String(rowId), 10));
    const rowsToDelete = rows.filter(row => rowIds.includes(row.id));
    setDeletedRows(rowsToDelete);
  }}
  rows={rows}
/>
```